# How do I downgrade a SQL 2008 MDF file for use in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Someone sent me a MDF file that was created in SQL 2008.  I have SQL 2005, and the "Attach" function is rejecting the MDF file.

How can I import this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. You need to attach to a SQL 2008 instance and synch/BCP/SSIS the schema and contents.

Blogged yesterday by [Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx) referring to SQL Server 2008/SQL Server 2008 R2 differences

Comment: ugh.  Not the answer I wanted, but accurate enough for answer credit... ;)